# Jelastic - vertical scaling

Tags: scaling, jelastic

I have an application on tomcat (no horizontal scaling), I send 20 requests. Each request executing complex calculations for 6-7 minutes.

I run the same on a standalone server with many cores (50+) and there each request is executed in a thread on the separate logical processor - execution time is 3-4 minutes.

On the Jelastic platform, it scales up to 40-42 cloudlets (even if max is 92). Is there a way "influence" scaling, to tell Jelastic that it should use more cloudlets. (I suppose there is less than 20 processors on 42 cloudlets and time is shared between threads).

Also if I send twice more (40 requests) it uses around 65 cloudlets (max, in that case, is set to 160).

Could I find anywhere what are rules how Jelastic decide how to scale and what to do to use more cloudlets?

Comment: Wisza, the answer below provided by @Damien-Layershift describes the situation  quite well. The performance and scaling depend on your code, app server configurations and cloud provider you chose as Jelastic partners use different hardware. If you still face issues or uncertainty please send us details about the service provider, account and env name to support@jelastic.com. We will analyse your case deeper.

Answer (score 1):

The overall compute power of your Jelastic node is determined by the cloudlet **scaling limit**. If you have a compute intensive workload, you should set this value as high as possible, keeping in mind your budget constraints. (you can also configure load alerts to notify you about persistent excessive usage)

The cloudlet consumption (in terms of billing) is calculated as the average CPU usage per hour, so if you have a spike of a few minutes - as in your example - you will want to allow it to use as much CPU as it can.

The usage that you see displayed is a function of how your workload is spreading across cores, with potentially artificial limitations on the actual compute power of each core due to the cloudlet limits that you've set. To get the best performance, you have to allow a very high cloudlet limit, because this will give you full access to each core instead of an (effectively) limited clock speed per core.

What you set as reserved cloudlets doesn't matter (it's purely a billing construct: no technical implications), and no cloudlets are added or removed from your server - again, this is purely a billing construct, not a technical one. This means there is no way to instruct Jelastic to use more cloudlets: that's happening purely due to how your code is executed (most likely the way it's spread across cores due to the overall cloudlet limits you've set vs. the compute power of the underlying hardware).

There is also a possibility that your performance will be different across different Jelastic providers depending on their hardware choices. For example some will use a high number of cores with lower clock speed, others may prioritise clock speed over the number of cores. Your application performance in that case will depend on how effectively it can be parallelised across cores (multi-threading); if your most intensive chunk of work doesn't parallelise, it will work best with a higher clock speed. Given that you get increased cloudlet consumption with more requests, it sounds like this is at least partially responsible in your case.

You might also consider that if you have better performance from dedicated hardware, you can get Jelastic as a private or hybrid cloud option. They may also offer different hardware options in different regions to cater for different types of workloads. Talk to your Jelastic provider and see what they can offer you.